# Is there a way to subscribe to a question?

Tags: support, notifications

And thus be notified in my SE global inbox (not email) of any edits, comments, new answers, etc?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]

You can [favorite a question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53585/how-do-favorite-questions-work) for that, when you do that you will get this relevant benefit:

> Changes to the question will now notify users who have favorited the question. Notifications include comments to the question, edits, new answers, and edits to answers. This is a way to get updates on questions that you yourself didn't ask.

This benefit includes all the notifications you have required in your meta question.

Comment: Where do I get notifications for Favorites? I have favorited many questions, but not once received a notification. Perhaps, I should start a new question for my issue...

Comment: I'm not entirely sure whether it's in the inbox or at the top of the page, it has been a long time ago one of my favorites has changed. I don't have many favorites so I can't really tell...

Comment: Strange. It does not seem to be working for me. I have asked about my issue here: http://meta.superuser.com/questions/3910/why-dont-i-get-notications-for-favorited-questions