# Why don't I get notications for favorited questions?

Tags: support

According to [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53585/how-do-favorite-questions-work) on Meta.StackOverflow:

> Changes to the question will now notify users who have favorited the
>   question. Notifications include comments to the question, edits, new
>   answers, and edits to answers. This is a way to get updates on
>   questions that you yourself didn't ask.

The answer does not explicitly state where the notifications appear, although I assume they would appear in my Stack Exchange inbox. However, I have not once received a single notification for any of the questions I have favorited.

Cross referencing my [inbox](http://stackexchange.com/users/962733?tab=inbox) and [favorites](https://superuser.com/users/100787/iglvzx?tab=favorites), I can confirm that there are no notifications for any activity from my favorites.

So, where are these notifications supposed to appear? Is this feature broken?

Comment: It's the same for me. Edits to my posts also aren't in the inbox. I need to go to my user profile (clicking my user name), and the tabs (e.g. *responses*, *favorites*) have number tags informing me of "unread messages".

Comment: I'm totally adding this to my favorites so I *don't* get a notification (yup, doesn't work for me either).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We had to pull that for a bit while we figure it out. See my comments here:

https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/52094

Comment: Please get it back soon

Comment: Have you figured it out yet? The star, as-is, is pretty much useless.

Comment: I'm glad I don't get a notification. I just want it to be in my favorites list so I can go look at it later. So if it *is* added, I want an option to *not* get notifications for every new answer on a favorite question.