# Inbox for Favourited items

Tags: bug, bookmarks, globalinbox

Questions that are favourited should show up with an Inbox notification for events, such as comments or answers, or even an answer getting accepted as the right one

Comment: Once upon a time, there was notifications. See my question here: http://meta.superuser.com/questions/3910/why-dont-i-get-notications-for-favorited-questions

Comment: I have [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/ngwD8.png) in the StackExchange dropdown, in *notifications*. Doesn't it work properly?

Comment: @DanielBeck Never seen that before

Comment: @Luke You did notice the fourth tab labeled *notifications* though? [Screenshot](http://i.stack.imgur.com/CURiO.png)? It contains favorites (at least the one I posted above) and badges.

Comment: @DanielBeck The only notifications that seem to show up for me are when I get badges

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just so this can be cleared... It appears that I now have the Notifications area on my inbox